# Image between two inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website using HTML & CSS from scratch. But now I have a problem in a specific section. The next image describes what I need:
[image]
And this is what I actually have:
[image]
My `#article-who` has `display: inline-block` (I can split it in two sections after). But the problem is about the `#square-logo`. If I use `inline-block` the div doesn't stack in the same line. I can move this element into my article, but what happens with the image of the right?

Please give me some idea using `div's` with fixed height and width.
Thanks in advance !

Edit: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zbg2dwu6/) is my current HTML & CSS (the preview generated in the fiddle is different in full screen).

Comment: can you post your full html/css code?

Comment: @JokerFan I have edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.container {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
.one {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
}
.two {
  background-color: indigo;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.three {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.four {
  background-color: indianred;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.five {
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
.align {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one align"></div>
  <div class="two align"></div>
  <div class="three align"></div>
  <div class="four align"></div>
  <div class="five align"></div>
</div>
```

I did a quick fix to last element i.e `.five` by applying `margin-top` in negative.

Comment: Simple, great answer.

Comment: Since I used ```inline-block``` elements for the first sections of the page, I thought I could not use the ```float``` property. But it works great within its container. Thanks! http://i.imgur.com/A3vyDSn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use span tag instead of div tag...because div tag seems to append a line break at the end..but span tag does not.
Try using multiple span tags inside a div tag to make it as a whole single block
`<div> 
   <span> </span> 
    <span> </span>
  </div>`